# Stack Overflow for Teams - Mobile

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, stack-overflow-app

**Did not find any info on this, please correct if I missed**

I have the mobile apps for Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange and I cannot see any of my team info on either of these apps.

Is there a way to enable this that I did not see?

Any instruction or information would be welcome.

Comment: I doubt that will be magically available. If anything I would expect it in the StaclOverflow app. Keep in mind though that app development is on hiatus at the moment

Comment: I would not expect magic but for a paid product I would expect something even if development is on hold.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mobile apps do not currently support Stack Overflow for Teams. However, it does work in the browser on your phone via the mobile skin.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Unfortunate, perhaps if more sign up there will be $ for this.  I saw that it works fine in the mobile browser.